# Button's cause validation property is set to false but still it fires validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, grid

I have a button in `EmptyTempletField` of `gridview` for which `causevalidation` property is set to `false`.

But when I try to add row in `gridview` from empty template field by clicking on that button, the button is not firing row command event. Moreover, it fires the validation. I have few validations which are grouped. But this button fires all validations irrespective of group. If I click on the button second time, then it fires the row command event. I can't understand what is happening..

Why button fires validation which it is not supposed to fire...???

Comment: Please add some code so we may be able to help you!

Comment: Code is too long to add here...:(

Comment: can't you post only relevant code?

Comment: If the real code is too long, maybe you could create a small example that shows this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is exaclty happening with your code. Anyway, it should be something similar to this

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDeletePicture" runat="server" CommandName="YOURCOMMAND"  Text="command" CausesValidation="false"  />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

protected void GV_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "YOURCOMMAND")
        {
             //your code 
        }
    }
```

And read this article about [GridView.RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx), which is helpful

Hope this helps